# JavaScript - is there any way (without using html event attributes) to get 3 different input values to contribute towards a sum?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, user-interface

I am completing the 57 programming exercises book by Brian P. Hogan.

With most of these exercises, I've tried to develop a GUI.

In the following exercise, I want to calculate the Simple Interest of a Principal value over a period of years. Simply put:

```
var yearlyInterest = Principal * (Percentage(whole number) /= 100)

(yearlyInterest * numberOfYears) + Principal

// outputs total amount at the end of investment over a period of however many years
```

As you can see in the example above, there are three core inputs - Principal, Percentage and Time.

When creating the graphical user interface, I am struggling to get all of these core inputs to calculate the result simultaneously.

The following code only manages to calculate the result once I enter the number for the Time input. (excuse my poor coding skills i.e. global variables, I'm only up to exercise 12!)

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
    <label for="principal">Principal</label>
    <input type="number" class="principal" style="border-color: black;">

    <label for="percentage">Percentage</label>
    <input type="number" class="percentage" style="border-color: black;">

    <label for="time">Time</label>
    <input type="number" class="time" style="border-color: black;">

    <div id="result"></div>
</body>
<script src="simpleInterest.js"></script>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
var principal = document.getElementsByClassName("principal");
var percentage = document.getElementsByClassName("percentage");
var time = document.getElementsByClassName("time");
var output = document.querySelector("#result");
var result;
var newResult;
var finalOutput;

document.addEventListener('input', function (event) {

    if ( event.target.classList.contains( 'principal' ) ) {
        var newPrincipal = principal[0].value;
        result = newPrincipal;
    }

    if ( event.target.classList.contains( 'percentage' ) ) {
        var newPercentage = percentage[0].value;
        newResult = result * (newPercentage / 100);
    }

    if ( event.target.classList.contains( 'time' ) ) {
        var newTime = time[0].value;
        finalOutput = (newResult * newTime) + Number(result);
    }

    output.innerHTML = `${finalOutput ? finalOutput : ""}`
}, false);
```

Could somebody please show me an effective way to simultaneously calculate something based on each input event and output it using the .innerHTML method?

Thanks!

Comment: Please get in the habit of putting semicolons at the end of each statement. ASI can easily produce unexpected results.

Comment: You may remove that Amazon link to the Book, as it can be percieved as spam. Also, i think mentioning the name and the author is enought information for people actually interested in buying it

Comment: Done! My apologies

Comment: You will make your life much easier if you change those input classes to IDs. Easier to select and also more correct (since you'll only have one occurrence of "principal", etc)

Comment: Also, while not totally implemented in all browsers, HTML 5 has an element `output` that would be ideal for your usecase. Instead of just a div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the values of all the inputs, not just the one that the user is currently typing in. Define a single function that does this, and add it as an event listener for all 3 inputs.

```js
var principal = document.querySelector(".principal");
var percentage = document.querySelector(".percentage");
var time = document.querySelector(".time");
var output = document.querySelector("#result");

function calcInterest() {
  var newPrincipal = parseFloat(principal.value);
  var newPercentage = parseFloat(percentage.value);
  var newTime = parseFloat(time.value);
  if (!isNaN(newPrincipal) && !isNaN(newPercentage) && !isNaN(newTime)) {
    var result = newPrincipal + newTime * newPrincipal * newPercentage / 100;
    output.textContent = result;
  }
}

principal.addEventListener("input", calcInterest);
percentage.addEventListener("input", calcInterest);
time.addEventListener("input", calcInterest);
```

```html
<label for="principal">Principal</label>
<input type="number" class="principal" style="border-color: black;"><br>

<label for="percentage">Percentage</label>
<input type="number" class="percentage" style="border-color: black;"><br>

<label for="time">Time</label>
<input type="number" class="time" style="border-color: black;"><br> Result:
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create function to calculate, and call this function instead of just executing some code. Something like that:

```js
var principal = document.getElementsByClassName("principal")
var percentage = document.getElementsByClassName("percentage")
var time = document.getElementsByClassName("time")
var output = document.querySelector("#result")
var result
var newResult
var finalOutput

var calculate = () => {
  var newPrincipal = principal[0].value;
  result = newPrincipal
  var newPercentage = percentage[0].value
  newResult = result * (newPercentage / 100)
  var newTime = time[0].value
  finalOutput = (newResult * newTime) + Number(result)
}

document.addEventListener('input', function (event) {

    if ( event.target.classList.contains( 'principal' ) ) {
        calculate();
    }

    if ( event.target.classList.contains( 'percentage' ) ) {
        calculate();
    }

    if ( event.target.classList.contains( 'time' ) ) {
        calculate();
    }

    output.innerHTML = `${finalOutput ? finalOutput : ""}`
}, false);
```